# How to put Image and Text inside 1 cell in iText Android table?

Tags: android, itext

How to put image and text below/above it?

I tried below code but I only can see "Test 1" and "Test 3"

```
private void createTable(Paragraph paragraph, Document document){
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Question"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Answer"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    HierarchyElement formElement;
    FormController formController = Collect.getInstance().getFormController();
    Image imageAnswer = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < mFormList.size(); i++){
        formElement = mFormList.get(i);

        table.addCell(formElement.getPrimaryText());

        String imageName = getImageNameOfSelectedAnswer(formController, formElement);
        if(imageName != null){
            imageAnswer = Image.getInstance(imageName);
            imageAnswer.scalePercent((float) 0.1);
        }

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Test 1"));
        cell.addElement(new Chunk(imageAnswer, 0, 0, true));
        cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Test 3"));
        table.addCell(cell);
    }

    paragraph.add(table);
    document.add(paragraph);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);  
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
paragraph1.add(textAnswer);
cell.addElement(paragraph1);
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Test 1"));
cell.addElement(imageAnswer);
cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Test 3"));
table.addCell(cell);
```

If that doesn't work, please provide a SSCCE that reproduces the problem in Java.

Comment: Your changes don't reflect what I said in my answer... You don't even wrap the image inside a `Chunk`, you just add it to a `Paragraph` expecting that a square peg fits in a round hole.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't update the code above there with your code. Now I update it but still the image doesn't show up.. Is it the correct way to do it? Sorry but I am very new to iText :D

Comment: I also tried code here http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PdfPCell-with-image-text-td2172268.html but still doesn't work :(

Comment: It seems there is something error when scaling. When I remove the scaling and use your code, now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I noticed that you scaled the image to 10%, but I didn't think that would be a problem: when adding an ´Image´ straight to a ´PdfPCell´, the ´PdfPCell´ usually takes care of scaling the image (so that it fits in the cell). In any case: I'm glad you found a solution that works!

Comment: Yeah I thought so.. Now I left the image automatically fit to the PdfPCell.. Thanks Bruno for your great library! :D