# Image with Organized textual information iText Android

Tags: android, image, itext, cell

My requirement is to generate a PDF of records, having custom cell like following image.

[image]

On net, I have just came across simple layout cells with Image. Links [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-image-and-text-same-cell) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715101/how-to-put-image-and-text-inside-1-cell-in-itext-android-table) don't help me as my information organization is totally different.

Please direct me towards possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Apart from the fact that your table has 3 columns, 5 rows, and a first cell that has a rowspan of 5, *what is different in the examples you refer to?* Which problem did you experience when trying to adapt those examples to meet your needs?

Comment: So I will be using a table for single record?

Comment: So you'll be using nested tables, amirite? A master table that contains your records, and each cell contains one record in a detail table with 3 cols, 5 rows, and first cell rowspan 5, as explained by Bruno. Get some inspiration about nested tables here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/nested-tables

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks @AmedeeVanGasse